# Is error checking included in asynchronous transmission?

Tags: network-discovery

A couple of notes I read from said that asynchronous transmission does not include error checking as part of its protocol. Yet parity checks are used in asynchronous data transmission.

Comment: Do you mean ATM -- the layer-2 protocol? No, it does not include any error checking/correction mechanisms. It is assumed your layer-1 technology is not error prone, and higher level protocols can detect and deal with errors. IP (layer-3) and TCP/UDP (layer-4) have their own checksums.

Comment: @RickyBeam, IPv4 has a checksum, but IPv6 did away with that.

Comment: Another kind of error-checking is whether or not packets are guaranteed to arrive at all.  With UDP ports they are not, and with TCP ports they will be retransmitted if no ACK is received.